# I want to fetch the parent attribute but it returns undefined jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

This is my code:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.setting', function(e){
 alert($(this).parent().data('fieldtype'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="field">
  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 pad" style="">
    <textarea class="form-control field" name="key1" rows="3" data-fieldtype="test" data-group="">demo</textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 pad pointer movefield" data-key="1">
    <div><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 pad pointer setting" data-key="1">
    <div><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog">click me</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 pad pointer field-remove" data-key="1">
    <div>x</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now the problem is not getting the value of `data-fieldtype`, as this method it returns `undefined`.
And also suggest for getting the value of `data-group` as currently this one is blank

Comment: textarea isn't parent of `.setting`. Use `$(this).parent().find('[data-fieldtype]').data('fieldtype')`

Comment: it works man. Thanks A alot Bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `textarea` isn't parent of `.setting`. Parent of it is `#field` and you should find textarea in it.

```
$(this).parent().find('[data-fieldtype]').data('fieldtype')
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '.setting', function(e){
  console.log(
    $(this).parent().find('[data-fieldtype]').data('fieldtype')
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="field">
  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 pad" style="">
    <textarea class="form-control field" name="key1" rows="3" data-fieldtype="test" data-group="">demo</textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 pad pointer movefield" data-key="1">
    <div><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 pad pointer setting" data-key="1">
    <div><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog">click me</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 pad pointer field-remove" data-key="1">
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```